# mysql command line with xampp in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, command-line, xampp

I installed xampp. After I type `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` into terminal, I get

```
$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.23-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

I changed the root password in `/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`
The password in `localhost/phpmyadmin` agrees with the change made in the `config.inc.php` file.
When I type `mysql -u root -p` into terminal I get

```
The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages:
 * mysql-client-core-5.5
 * mariadb-client-core-5.5
 * mysql-client-core-5.6
 * percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.5
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I installed `mysql-client-core-5.6`

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.6
[sudo] password for experiment: 
Reading package lists... Done
```

After installing the client, when I typed `mysql -u root -p` into terminal I got

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Some threads suggest that multiple instances of mysql could be running.
When I type `ps ax | grep mysql` into terminal, I get

```
$ ps ax | grep mysql
 7021 ?        S      0:00 /bin/sh /opt/lampp/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/opt/lampp/var/mysql --pid-file=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/experiment-MP061.pid
 7168 ?        Sl     0:02 /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/opt/lampp --datadir=/opt/lampp/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/opt/lampp/lib/mysql/plugin/ --user=mysql --log-error=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/experiment-MP061.err --pid-file=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/experiment-MP061.pid --socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
11112 pts/6    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

I don't know how to interpret the output. Is this one instance of mysql?

Some threads suggest making changes to the `my.cnf` file. I don't have one. I do have a `etc/mysql/my.cnf.bak` file. Where should I put the my.cnf file?

Should I be able to use the mysql command line after installing xampp only or do I need to install a client?

My ultimate goal is to have a system where I can use xampp, Workbench, NetBeans, and the mysql command line.

Answer (score 0):

To find the path where my.cnf or my.ini is picked up, issue a command

```
mysql --help
```

It will echo out a lot of info. Search thru the text to find a line like the following:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
C:\WINDOWS\my.ini C:\WINDOWS\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.cnf
```

or

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

It is buried right in the middle of the echo output.

Lastly,

```
$ sudo netstat -tlpn | grep mysql
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      10954/mysqld
```

port 3306.

If you have a few daemons running, you will get multiple lines. You use the `-P` (uppercase) switch at the cmd line for the port number. Note that lowercase `-p` is for the password (either prompt for it or give it)